# Liquibase tag rollback command

Tags: database, liquibase, rollback, changeset, changelog

I want to run cmd liquibase rollaback tag :

```
java -jar demoLiquibase1-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar rollback 1.0;
```

but nothing it works

Can you help me?

Comment: Hard to help with so little information. Where did the demoLiquibase jar come from? What output was produced?

Comment: Resolved problem

Comment: Do you think you learned anything that might help future explorers with similar issues? If so, please share what you learned!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the liquibase core jar 3.8.0 then I added the path's Liquibase to envirment vars, so it works :)